# Scripts Not Enqueing

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress Scripts aren't enqueuing on my server. They are enqueuing fine on my localhost. Same set of code, same wordpress (4.9.5) and same plugins. Paths are relative and I checked the generated HTML anyway and the lines that load the scripts simply aren't being printed out on the "server" (running Apache), but works fine on my localhost (which runs on a local nginx server).

Never encountered this error before. Usually if something breaks like this, it breaks in both servers.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Despite duplicating the code and database, certain Jetpack settings aren't activated if you don't have JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG set on the server even though they are activated in my localhost copy of my database that I pushed to the server.